# SQLite, Copy DataSet / DataTable to DataBase file

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, datatable, dataset

I have filled a DataSet with a Table that was created from **another** database file.  The table is NOT in the database file which I want to be able to copy the Table to.

Now I want to save all those records (DataTable) to a newly created SQLite database file...

How can i do that?

Also I really want to avoid loops if this is possible.

The best answer is by me :) so i'll share it.This is loop but writes 100k entries in 2-3secs.

```
using (DbTransaction dbTrans = kaupykliuduomConn.BeginTransaction())
{
  downloadas.Visible = true; //my progressbar
  downloadas.Maximum = dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"].Rows.Count;

  using (DbCommand cmd = kaupykliuduomConn.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO duomenys(Barkodas, Preke, kiekis) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    DbParameter Field1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    DbParameter Field2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    DbParameter Field3 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Field1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Field2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Field3);

    while (n != dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"].Rows.Count)
    {
      Field1.Value = dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"].Rows[n]["Barkodas"].ToString();
      Field2.Value = dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"].Rows[n]["Preke"].ToString();
      Field3.Value = dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"].Rows[n]["kiekis"].ToString();
      downloadas.Value = n;
      n++;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  dbTrans.Commit();
}
```

In this case dataSet1.Tables["duomenys"] is already filled with all the data i need to transfer to another database. I used loop to fill dataset too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- When you load the `DataTable` from the source database, set the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the data adapter to false, so that loaded records are kept in the `Added` state (assuming that the source database is SQL Server)

  ```
  var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM the_table", sqlConnection);
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  sqlAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
  sqlAdapter.Fill(table);
  ```
- Create the table in the SQLite database, by executing the `CREATE TABLE` statement directly with `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`
- Create a new `DataAdapter` for the SQLite database connection, and use it to `Update` the db:

  ```
  var sqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM the_table", sqliteConnection);
  var cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqliteAdapter);
  sqliteAdapter.Update(table);
  ```

If the source and target tables have the same column names and compatible types, it should work fine...

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's working...but VERY VERY VERY slow... 32 thousand records to copy to database took like 3-4 minutes. and it only have 3 columns... strange why so slow?

Comment: Try to do the Update in a transaction; if there is no explicit transaction, SQLite creates one implicitly for each insert, which is very slow for massive inserts. Also, 32k records is pretty big, perhaps you should try to do it in smaller batches.

Comment: Was having a similar performance issue, adding the transaction solved it for me!

Comment: As SqlDataAdapter and SQLiteAdapter implement IDisposable interface, I think it is better to use "using" keyword with both objects, do you agree ?

Comment: @Jean-DanielGasser yes

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: thank you very much for the provided solution, the only thing is the cast of DateTime columns to SQLite which accepts only INTEGER or TEXT type for dates. Do you have an idea to manage the transformation between cols containing DateTime values to integer (ticks)?

Answer (score 7):

The way to import `SQL` data to `SQLite` will take long time. When you want to import data in millions, It will take lot of time. So the shortest and easiest way to do that is just fill fetch the data from SQL database in a `DataTable` and insert all its rows to `SQLite` database.

```
public bool ImportDataToSQLiteDatabase(string Proc, string SQLiteDatabase, params object[] obj)
    {
        DataTable result = null;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            result = new DataTable();
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                using (cmd = CreateCommand(Proc, CommandType.StoredProcedure, obj))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;Max Pool Size=100;", SQLiteDatabase)))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
                    {
                        using (SQLiteCommand sqlitecommand = new SQLiteCommand("insert into table(fh,ch,mt,pn) values ('" + Convert.ToString(row[0]) + "','" + Convert.ToString(row[1]) + "','"
                                                                                                                              + Convert.ToString(row[2]) + "','" + Convert.ToString(row[3]) + "')", con))
                        {
                            sqlitecommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                    new General().WriteApplicationLog("Data successfully imported.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

It will take a very few time as compare to upper given answers.